# How do you populate database in firebase?

Tags: database, firebase

How do you populate database in firebase?

I am hosting a website using firebase, and would like to know how to populate a database using firebase.

Comment: There is an entire website with documentation explaining how to do that and many other things: https://www.firebase.com/docs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://YOUR_FIREBASE_URL.firebaseio.com/");
ref.update({message:"Hello"});
```

About as easy as it gets.

Read more at: 
 https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can populate firebase Database from a JavaScript file by taking database ref to firebase and pushing objects to it.

`const postsRef = database().ref('posts');`

and then push objects to the ref.
`postsRef.push({})`

Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVG0YS7nIG0